# jquery to use a checkbox to toggle column visibility in a DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a DataTable with 20 columns. I want to have checkboxes above the table to turn column visibility on/off.

Found [this article](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/show_hide.html) that used links to do it but those links have hardcoded constants in the `<a>` elements representing the column index number. I was hoping to have checkboxes whose label is the same as the `<th>` elements in the table, and then have a click function to find the appropriate column and toggle the visibility for that column.

```
var animals = $('#animalTable').DataTable({
    columns: [
        { data: 'Id', visible: false },
        { data: 'Cats' },
        { data: 'Dogs' }
    ]
});

<table id="animalTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Cats</th>
      <th>Dogs</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

// a set of toggle checkboxes; one for each column
<input id="catscb" class="toggle-vis" type="checkbox" checked>
<label for="catscb">Cats</label>

<input id="dogscb" class="toggle-vis" type="checkbox" checked>
<label for="dogscb">Dogs</label>
```

This is the code from [the article](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/show_hide.html) that showed how to do it with hard coded column indexes in the "data-column" attribute. I would like to use checkbox's label to find the column instead.

```
$('input.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {

    // Get the column API object
    var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );
// 'data-column' above is the issue... hardcoded number in the <a> elements

    column.visible( ! column.visible() );
});
```

I tried making a loop to go over all columns but I'm not sure what kind of thing `this.data()` is inside the function. If that's a column structure then how to find its `<th>` value, and if a match, how to toggle that column's visibility?

```
// loop over all columns DataTable, even hidden ones (I hope that's what this does)
animals.columns().every( function () {
    var col = this.data();

    // compare this col's <th> to "Dogs" (since Dogs checkbox was
    // checked) and if a match, get the col index for Dogs column 
    // and toggle its visibility
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your code, I assume you are expecting ID column to be hidden here. I added a class to each label with same name it's correspondent Checkbox Id, so You just need to set a new variable for your Label name and use it to ask for column index :)
I don't advise using it if you are expecting tables with heavy datasets... the script could get lazy looking for the targeted column.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var animals = $('#animalTable').DataTable({
    columns: [
        { name: 'Id', visible: false },
        { name: 'Cats' },
        { name: 'Dogs' }
    ]
});
 
    $('input.toggle-vis').on( 'change', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    var idv = $(this).attr('id');
    var namelab=$('label[class="' + idv + '"]').text();
    
    //var nicename = namelab+':name';
    var idx = animals.column(namelab+':name').index();
    //console.log(idx);
        // Get the column API object
        var column = animals.column( idx );
 
        // Toggle the visibility
        column.visible( ! column.visible() );
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<input id="catscb" class="toggle-vis" type="checkbox" checked>
<label class="catscb" for="catscb">Cats</label>

<input id="dogscb" class="toggle-vis" type="checkbox" checked>
<label class="dogscb" for="dogscb">Dogs</label>


<table id="animalTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Cats</th>
      <th>Dogs</th>
    </tr>
    
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Cat 1</td>
                <td>Dog1</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Cat2</td>
                <td>Dog2</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Cat3</td>
                <td>DOg3</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Cat4</td>
                <td>DOg4</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>Cat5</td>
                <td>DOg5</td>

            </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I prefer official guidelines so Following the article you mentioned which is better in performance by using column index, I made you this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1nwt5Lsx/